# C# DataGridView ComboBox Binding Issues

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I've got a C# program that I'm working on but I can't get the ComboBoxColumn to display as I want it to.

I have two tables. One Contains a list of price. (Columns: PriceID, PartID, Price, MinimumQuantity, CustomerID, ExpiryDate) The other table, a list of parts contains (Columns: PartID, PartNumber). What

I want to do is display the PartNumber in a ComboBoxColumn with the PartID as the value. But I want to corresponding part number selected automatically for each price row.

Does this make sense!?

What I am currently getting in each row is the prices, quantities and expiry dates and ComboBoxColumn with the parts list populating the combobox but no value selected.

Please can someone help me with this.

Please see the code below.

```
        DbConnection dbConn = new DbConnection(getConnectionStr());
        dbConn.execQuery("EXEC RBS_CustomerSpecificPriceListSelect " + customerID + ";", "CustomerPriceList");
        dbConn.execQuery("EXEC RBS_PartsSelect;", "Parts");

        DataTable dtCustomerPrices = dbConn.getDataTable("CustomerPriceList");
        DataTable dtParts = dbConn.getDataTable("Parts");

        dgvCustomerPrices.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvCustomerPrices.DataSource = dtCustomerPrices;
        dgvCustomerPrices.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.AllCells;

        SetupDGVColumns(dtCustomerPrices, dtParts);
```

Then to generate the columns.

```
    private void SetupDGVColumns(DataTable dtCustomerPrices, DataTable dtParts)
    {
        // Parts Dropdown
        DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cboPartsColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
        cboPartsColumn.DisplayStyle = DataGridViewComboBoxDisplayStyle.Nothing;
        cboPartsColumn.DataSource = dtParts;
        cboPartsColumn.HeaderText = "PartNumber";
        cboPartsColumn.DisplayMember = "PartNumber";
        cboPartsColumn.ValueMember = "PartID";
        cboPartsColumn.DataPropertyName = "PartID";
        cboPartsColumn.Width = 110;
        cboPartsColumn.AutoComplete = true;
        dgvCustomerPrices.Columns.Add(cboPartsColumn);

        // MinimumQuantity Textbox
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tbcMinimumQuantityColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        tbcMinimumQuantityColumn.DataPropertyName = "MinimumQuantity";
        tbcMinimumQuantityColumn.HeaderText = "MinimumQuantity";
        tbcMinimumQuantityColumn.ValueType = typeof(double);
        tbcMinimumQuantityColumn.Width = 140;
        tbcMinimumQuantityColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#####0.00";
        dgvCustomerPrices.Columns.Add(tbcMinimumQuantityColumn);

        // Price Textbox
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tbcPriceColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        tbcPriceColumn.DataPropertyName = "Price";
        tbcPriceColumn.HeaderText = "Price";
        tbcPriceColumn.ValueType = typeof(double);
        tbcPriceColumn.Width = 100;
        tbcPriceColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#####0.00";
        dgvCustomerPrices.Columns.Add(tbcPriceColumn);

        // ExpiryDate Textbox
        DataGridViewTextBoxColumn tbcExpiryDateColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        tbcExpiryDateColumn.DataPropertyName = "ExpiryDate";
        tbcExpiryDateColumn.HeaderText = "ExpiryDate";
        tbcExpiryDateColumn.ValueType = typeof(string);
        tbcExpiryDateColumn.DefaultCellStyle.Format = "d";
        dgvCustomerPrices.Columns.Add(tbcExpiryDateColumn);
    }
```

Comment: To be certain, it's just the initial selection in the Cb columns that's not working? Can you change the PartId of a row?

Comment: Yes, I would have thought that you could bind the two tables together maybe and the combobox would select the correct ID value as it is bound to the other table. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: It looks OK, that's why I asked if it works in other aspects. Could have revealed a typo in a Column name or something.

Comment: Yes the data loads in both tables and the columns. I just want a way to relate a row to its current selected ID so they match.

Comment: Ok so does the relation matter in the SQL database!? I thought as long as the correct datapropertyname is set then the columns should bind!?

Basically I have done practically identical code in another form with different tables and I get the correct expected output of the part numbers being correctly selected for each row. WHY OH WHY!?!

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this was complete idiocy on my part. The SQL query that was selecting the combo columns data did not have the corresponding row ID in the SELECT clause.

Thank you all for your help though! I feel silly!